# Vaadin: table container has object members

Tags: java, vaadin

I'm extending the `BeanItemContainer` and using it as a container for a table in Vaadin.

```
public class MyContainer extends BeanItemContainer<MyClass>
        implements Serializable {
...
}
```

The `MyClass` object has a structure as shown below:

```
public class MyClass {
    private int id;
    private InnerClass data;
...
}
```

And the InnerClass has the structure:

```
public class InnerClass {
    private int propA;
    private String propB;
...
}
```

I'd like to display the id and data.propA columns but I'm not sure how to in Vaadin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use the `addNestedContainerProperty` property.

Refer to https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/datamodel.container.html for details.